# Torricelli points on a circle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

Points $P_{1}, P_{2}, P_{3}, \ldots, P_{n-1}$ are marked on side $BC$ of a regular triangle $ABC$, so that the rays $A P_{1}, A P_{2}, A P_{3}, \ldots, A P_{n-1}$ split $\angle B A C$ into $n$ equal angles. In this case, triangle $ABC$ is divided into $n$ triangles. The points $T_{1}, T_{2}, T_{3}, \ldots, T_{n}$ are the Torricelli points of these triangles.

- Prove that the points $T_{1}, T_{2}, T_{3}, \ldots, T_{n}, B, C$ lie on the same circle.
- Find the radius of this circle if $AB=1$.

[image]

According to my calculations, the radius of the circle is $R=\frac{1}{2 \sin \frac{\pi}{3 n}}$, but I do not yet know how to prove that the points lie on the same circle. I was told that it is necessary to prove that all angles $\angle B T_{i} C$ are equal to $\pi-\frac{\pi}{3 n}$.

P.S. The angle $A T_{i} P_{i}$ is $120^\circ$, so a circle is described around $A B P_{i} T_{i}$. Therefore, the angle $B T_{i} P_{i}$ is equal to $B A P_{i}$. For similar reasons, the angle $C T_{i} P_{i-1}$ is equal to $C A P_{i-1}$. Together, these angles give $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{3 n}$.

The angle $B T_{i} C$ consists of the two angles mentioned above and the angle $P_{i-1} T_{i} P_{i}$, which is equal to $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$. Therefore, it is equal to $\pi-\frac{\pi}{3 n}$, whence it is clear that it does not depend on $i$, therefore all Torricelli points lie on the circle.

If $R$ is its radius, then by the sine theorem $2 R \sin \frac{\pi}{3 n}=B C=1$, which allows us to find $R$.

Comment: Please show your derivation for  $R=\frac{1}{2 \sin \dfrac{\pi}{3 n}}$

Comment: @Narasimham I don’t understand why you need this, you cannot calculate it yourself? Anyway, I covered this point in the question and also answered the 1st question.

Comment: @ReneMorningstar: When asking someone for assistance, it's good practice to minimize the burden associated with that assistance. Showing work you have done on a problem is part of that. It helps people avoid wasting their valuable time duplicating your effort. Also, it gives a sense of the types of tools and techniques familiar to you, which can help people avoid explaining things you already understand. Moreover, it may be possible that work you've done only needs a little tweak to get to the solution you need.

Comment: To clarify, your edit is the solution to the question right? If so, can you make that  clear instead of just using a post-script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1:

Do not know if the following construction is any useful HINT.

All Fermat points $T_i$ have three $120^{\circ}$ vertices that surround them.

The Toricelli-Fermat Points minimize distances to vertices in a *geometrical* sense for each triangle by an algebraic/differential calculus procedure .

In an  more inclusive *physical* sense we see three equal forces symmetrically contribute to a static stability when they have equal subtended angles at all points when a prismatic net has soap bubbles at any of $(120^{\circ})$ nodes trying to equally pull the common $T_i$ node point away.I.e., the given regiven was imagined to look somewhat to a triangular sector.

Attempted to realize inside a new airfoil-like boundary (of adequate strength or rigidity). I suppose such a honeycomb structure region would be stable for all $AP_i T_i$ points.

I.e., the given region was imagined to look somewhat similar to a thin concave lens in a triangulated configuration including point A..

Remember the 4- point motorway total path minimizing surface tension problem solution? If polyurethane foam is cast into such a closed mold, each closed cell could form this way (ie filled with a maze of Toricelli points). I tried to hand sketch one.. how a narrower airfoil like contour region would be populated with more such Torricelli trianguled nodes.

Even now I have not been 100% complete with a proper answer... taking support of the Queen of sciences  itself is perhaps still a valid answer recourse or so I thought!

[image]

[image]

Comment: To check, does it make sense to you that your answer was accepted? It seems to me that you wanted to post an image, and that you do not know if it is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain adequately then.. partly because I could not collect my relevant thoughts together for a cogent answer. Perhaps you could have nudged me on to defend it to be clearer with an answer. ( If it made no sense I would not waste anyone's attention unless it was tagged as a soft question and so on at any rate acceptance is no consideration at all ). I have updated along similar lines to be clearer hopefully. Hope you enjoyed the discussion at least.